# the "body" field is not valid in Lotus Notes select formula?

Tags: view, selection, lotus

I created a view to show the important mails for me.
To set the selection criteria I used the following formula:

```
SELECT @Contains (body, "important")
```

But this formula returns NO documents.
On the other hand, below formula show me the right set of documents:

```
SELECT @Contains (subject, "important")
```

So, the field "body" is not valid in lotus notes formula?
I tried other words, such as "BodyText", "message", etc. No one seems correct.

Does anybody know the answer?
I am using: IBM Notes9 Social Edition

Answer (score 2):

"Body" is a rich text field, hence its contents can not be used in a selection formula.  A selection formula can only use a "summary" field, not a rich text one.

See [this](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/e24a77e53e355d0885256ff0005dab2f?OpenDocument) conversation on the Notes Forum for more information

**EDIT**: 
As Per Kenrik said in the comments, it is not because the field is called "body", it is because the field called "body", in your case (I'm guessing it's emails), is a Rich Text field.

Comment: @GangLi it’s not because of the name “body” but because the field in your case is a Rich Text field and not a “plain” text field

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative of ‘body’ which is a plain text field? Or, can I convert body to plain text? My purpose is to also do filtering on body, not only on header fields. Mail rule is not that good to use since I have complex rules.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new computed field named body2 with  @Abstact(body) formula. After that you can use body2 field for selection criteria. Works only in new documents. you can run an agent with similar formula to set old documents.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know this works for languages other than English or not? Such as Japanese.

Comment: it works for Turkish. I did not try it, but i dont think it would be a problem for Japanese.